# std::is_member_function_pointer not working for overloaded functions?

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, traits

I've written a trait that detects whether a class has a certain public member function via `std::is_member_function_pointer`:

```
class Test1
{
public:
    void method();
};

class Test2
{
public:
    void method();
    void method(int);
};

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct HasMethod : std::false_type
{
};

template <typename T>
struct HasMethod<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_member_function_pointer<decltype(&T::method)>::value>>
    : std::true_type
{
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << HasMethod<Test1>::value << std::endl; // prints 1
    std::cout << HasMethod<Test2>::value << std::endl; // prints 0
}
```

However it seems that when the function is overloaded, then `std::is_member_function_pointer` is not able to detect it, as shown with `Test2`.
Is there a way to make it work regardless of whether the method is overloaded?

Comment: It is not a problem with `std::is_member_function_pointer`. It is a problem of `&T::method`: which overload's address should be returned in this case?

Comment: Good point. I guess I would need to disambiguate by casting the pointer to a given signature. But is there a way to templatize this trait so that any signature can work?

Comment: Why would you want any signature to work? The eventual goal would be to call that function, no? You can't call it if you don't know what arguments to pass.

Comment: I got it to work, check edited answer below.

Answer (score 1):

To detect existence of class members usual approach is to use `std::void_t` template. You can do it like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class Test1
{
public:
    void method();
};

class Test2
{
public:
    void method();
    void method(int);
};

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct HasMethod : std::false_type
{
};

// Use method(0) to detect void method(int) overload
// You don't even need std::void_t in this case, since method returns void anyway, but for any other return type you will need it
template <typename T>
struct HasMethod<T, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().method())>>
    : std::true_type
{
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << HasMethod<Test1>::value << std::endl; // prints 1
    std::cout << HasMethod<Test2>::value << std::endl; // prints 1
}
```

---

Ok. After some thinking I found solution. We can use fact that `declval(&T::method)` will fail, if there is more than one overload, to detect if we have at least one overload, by adding another one. Here is solution. It is quite verbose, but I was unable to reduce it. At least it works.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class Test
{
};

class Test1
{
public:
    void method();
};

class Test2
{
public:
    void method();
    void method(int);
};

class Test3
{
public:
    using method = int;
};

class Test4
{
public:
    int method;
};

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct HasSingleOverload : std::false_type {};
template<typename T>
struct HasSingleOverload<T, std::void_t<decltype(&T::method)>> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct IsMemberFunction : std::false_type {};
template<typename T>
struct IsMemberFunction<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_member_function_pointer<decltype(&T::method)>::value>> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct IsType : std::false_type {};
template<typename T>
struct IsType<T, std::void_t<typename T::method>> : std::true_type {};

struct HasOverload {
    void method();
};

template<typename T>
struct CheckOverload : T, HasOverload {
};

template<typename T>
using HasConflict = std::bool_constant<!HasSingleOverload<CheckOverload<T>>::value>;

template<typename T>
using HasAnyOverload = std::conditional_t<HasSingleOverload<T>::value || IsType<T>::value, IsMemberFunction<T>, HasConflict<T>>;

int main()
{
    std::cout << HasAnyOverload<Test>::value << std::endl; // prints 0
    std::cout << HasAnyOverload<Test1>::value << std::endl; // prints 1
    std::cout << HasAnyOverload<Test2>::value << std::endl; // prints 1
    std::cout << HasAnyOverload<Test3>::value << std::endl; // prints 0
    std::cout << HasAnyOverload<Test4>::value << std::endl; // prints 0
}
```

Comment: [This doesn't work either](https://godbolt.org/z/KTfb85ox1).

Comment: @n.m. This variant works only for specific overload, not for any of them. If you want to detect `method(float)` overload you can either use `method(0.f)` or `method(float{})` inside `declval()`.

Comment: Exactly, "is there a way to templatize this trait so that any signature can work?" this isn't one.

Comment: @n.m. This answer was created before this request. BUT, I think I have idea how to do this, will try to do it now...

Comment: I don't think it's possible...

Comment: @n.m. I got it to work, check second solution.

Comment: This will return `true` for a class with any kind of member named `method`. Not just a member function but also a data member or a typedef or a class template.

Comment: @n.m. Well, yes. But depending on what was OP's goal this can work for him...

Comment: @n.m. Ok. Now it is even more verbose, but I fixed this issue.

Comment: Yeah it starts to be rather complicated, and it still doesn't catch `template<int> struct method{};`. I'm almost sure this is not really possible to catch, but one probably doesn't need to, the original method of detecting a member with a known signature should be enough.